# Extract SVM assigned values against each instance in WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, svm, weka, libsvm, liblinear

is there any way for extracting the values after using SVM traning model against each instance to see what value SVM has assigned to each instance for classifying the instance in either positive class or negative.. i am looking for some solution to get all the SVM based assigned valus against each instance in WEKA tool.
i have been using LibSVM and LibLinear classifiers under SVM. i need those values to use for ranking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Click Preprocess... Filter ... "Choose" Button...
- Then select the Weka /Filters / Supervised / Attribute Filter
  "AddClassification"
- In its configuration Dialog, set "OutputClassification" to "True"
- Click on the "LibSVM" label to invoke the second dialog box. Configure the Classifier.
- Click apply.

A new column "Classification" will be added to your dataset - but this won't perform cross-validation on your dataset. It will use the entire dataset as training dataset and thus will lead to overfitting.

Alternative (for getting predictions on cross-validated output): You can also go to the "Classifier" tab, click "More Options..." button, "Output predictions", choose "PlainText" then the predictions will show up in the big "Classifier Output" textpanel.

Comment: Thanks for guiding. but there is no such option like "OutputClassification" in the second dialog box we get after clicking the "LibSVM" label. that ialog box has following options in it
Svm type, batchsize, cachesize, coef(), cost, debug, degree, doNotCheckCapabilities, doNotReplaceMissingValues, eps, gamma, kernelType, loss, modelFile, normalize, nu, numDecimalPlaces, probabilityEstimates, seed, shrinking ans weights

Comment: I've switched two lines in my bulleted list - see my edits. The "AddClassification" filter has its own Configuration Dialog, there you can find "OutputClassification"